# how to connect from local application to distant hive?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I'm working in my windows machine on an application that need to coonect to hive tables which created in distant redhat machine. I m using java spring boot. I m tring to connect using:

```
   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://my_machine_hostname:10000/mydatabase", "my_username", "mypassword");
```

and I get this error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: 
    jdbc:hive2://my_machine_hostname:10000/my_database: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:224) ~[hive-jdbc-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) ~[hive-jdbc-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at com.orange.SearchEngineHive.Repositories.SearchEngineRepo.getData(SearchEngineRepo.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
```

when I tried to connect from an other machine, the connection succeeded.

Comment: Does `my_machine_hostname` resolve correctly?

Comment: Yes , it does ! because when I tried to connect from an other host it succeeded.

Comment: Does the machine you are using resolve `my_machine_hostname` from the command line? If yes, then this is specific to Java. Please check the Certs.

Comment: did you try connecting from another machine in java program or shell?

Comment: This looks fine, but remote Hive version needs to match your JDBC driver version